# Talend: how to fork the output of a parent job and call either of child job based on some condition

Tags: talend

I am learning Talend. I have a scenario where I have to apply if else if condition to the output from the parent job and based on the outcome, call either of the child jobs. I have thought of few options such as using global variables or context variables. Is it possible to configure the child jobs to listen to the global/context variable change and run if the condition match? I tried looking to configure this, but failed to understand where can I do these configurations.

I even tried taking the output from the parent job component's into a tjavarow where I can write java code with if else if conditions. I was thinking to explicitly call the sub jobs from the if else branching, but I am not able to make any headway. Can someone please direct me through the right approach? Any new approach is also welcomed.

NOTE: We are using free version of Talend.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this can be achieved using "Run If" triggers, like this:

[image]

Inside tJava, you can write some logic to calculate your variables.
On the If trigger, you write a condition that determines whether or not the component after it is run.

In my example, I'm not actually making use of what's inside tJava, I'm just getting the number of lines output by tLogRow, so it can be left out and the "Run If" triggers connected directly to tLogRow.